# Cannot upgrade software on ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1087-aws x86_64) due to dependency issues

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, dpkg, amazon-ec2, bzip2

I am running ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1087-aws x86_64) on an AWS EC2 t3a.nano instance. When I accessed my box over SSH, I see this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1087-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  [redacted]
 * Management:     [redacted]
 * Support:        [redacted]

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    [redacted]

132 packages can be updated.
3 updates are security updates.
```

Wanting to keep the software on my box up-to-date, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 [redacted] xenial InRelease
Hit:2 [redacted] xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Reading package lists... Done
```

Then I entered:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Okay, so I see I have dependency issues, so I try:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  bzip2 libbz2-1.0
Suggested packages:
  bzip2-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bzip2 libbz2-1.0
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 126 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 63.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 [redacted] xenial-updates/main amd64 bzip2 amd64 1.0.6-8ubuntu0.2 [32.5 kB]
Get:2 [redacted] xenial-updates/main amd64 libbz2-1.0 amd64 1.0.6-8ubuntu0.2 [30.7 kB]
Fetched 63.2 kB in 0s (3,126 kB/s)    
Selecting previously unselected package bzip2.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
```

Now that I see that dpkg exited unexpectedly, I try:

```
sudo dpkg --audit
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 bzip2                high-quality block-sorting file compressor - utilities
```

I try:

```
sudo apt-get install bzip2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bzip2 : Depends: libbz2-1.0 (= 1.0.6-8ubuntu0.2) but 1.0.6-8ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So now I try:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  bzip2 libbz2-1.0
Suggested packages:
  bzip2-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bzip2 libbz2-1.0
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 126 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/63.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package bzip2.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
```

Now I'm going in circles. Any ideas?

---

*Edit to address comment from* @fkraiem:
When I go to /etc/apt/sources.list, I see:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
[...]
```

Are you suggesting that I replace us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com with packages.ubuntu.com and retry the update commands?

Comment: Since you are using an unknown and probably unofficial mirror, there's a possibility it might be giving you corrupted packages. Try getting them from an official mirror (*e.g.*, through packages.ubuntu.com).

Comment: I can try updating the references in /etc/apt/sources.list if that's how. BTW, the reason it says "redacted" is because StackExchange limits # of URLs per question. They are:
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:3 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]

Comment: @guiverc No, the package indexes are not out-of-date; `1.0.6-8ubuntu0.2` is indeed the latest version of `bzip2` for Xenial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone that offered comments and tried to help.

In the end, at one point I did:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and noticed an error about insufficient memory. I was using a t3a.nano which only offers 0.5G of memory. I tried adding 0.5G of swap, then ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and tried the updates again and now everything is in tip-top shape.

For anyone looking at this that might also be using a nano instance, 0.5G isn't much memory, so you may want to consider adding swap to prevent these kinds of problems.  Here's how I did it:

```
sudo fallocate -l 0.5G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```